# Emacs Semantic/ECB namespace-struct C++ confusion

Tags: c++, emacs, emacs-ecb, emacs-semantic

I'm trying to setup ECB to work with C++ sources.
seemingly, semantic or ECB has problem determining whenever a function declarant with explicit namespace, `namespace:: function` , is really in the namespace. instead it parses it as struct member function.

Moreover, typedef is parsed as function prototypes.

What should I do to fix it? I am using cedet 1 .06pre and ECB 2.40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to take CEDET from CVS. as i remember were some fixes for such cases

Comment: hi Alex, CVS version is working. however STL completion is broken in class methods, such as vector. the symbol types are in type cache database, but do not resolve in debug assist. the message is "cannot find types for std::..."

Comment: Please send piece of code, that produce this error to the cedet-devel mailing list